# Sprocket and Rails 3.1: Load different files depending on which controller is loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sprockets

I have been looking over the web for this but I can't seem to find documentation for what I'm looking for.

I have a rails application and depending on which controller is used, I want to serve different css/js files.

Right now, I can either load **EVERY** file or only application.(css|js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue after a good night of sleep. Here's the solution:

application.html.erb

```
<html>
 <head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", controller_name, "template"%>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" , controller_name %>
 </head>
</html>
```

controller.js.coffee

```
//= require ender
```

controller.css.scss

```
//= require sub-template
```